# Force "Open in Firefox" for iframe in Firefox

Tags: pdf, firefox, acrobat

I have a webapp which has ability to print PDF blobs by creating `<iframe>` with `display: none` and then calling `.contentWindow.print()`. It works great in Chrome and Firefox with default configuration.

The problem appears when I have a setting `Open in other app: Acrobat Reader DC`:
[image]

If this is chosen, every time I mount `iframe` with `application/pdf` content to DOM I have Adobe Acrobat Reader opened with this PDF.

Is there any way to make Firefox treat PDF with default behaviour for particular webpage/iframe?

Comment: Clarification question Firefox will open a acrobat to print this, when the setting is on. Also a kind of crap solution you can check if it has that setting and just not display it as `application/pdf`